# iOS: I want to continuously rotate an image, but it doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cabasicanimation

Have the code from several examples on stackoverflow. But my image doesn't rotate..any idea why? It is displayed on the screen, but fixed..

```
-(UIImageView *)movablePropeller
{
    if(!_movablePropeller){
        _movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        _movablePropeller.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MovablePropeller"];
        [self addSubview:_movablePropeller];
    }
    return _movablePropeller;
}

- (void)startPropeller
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI)];
    rotation.cumulative = true;
    rotation.duration = 0.7f; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = INFINITY; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.

    [self.movablePropeller.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.movablePropeller.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
}
```

(and of course I would love to have it in a seperate thread, not to block the UI)

Comment: I assume you code is part of a UIView sub-class. Your code should work fine except for the `initWithFrame` which probably should use `self.bounds` instead of `self.frame`. Where do you call `startPropeller`?

Comment: Most likely the problem is that you’re calling `startPropeller` before you’ve added `movablePropeller` to the view hierarchy. See your follow-up question (and answer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020431/1271826