# MBProgressHUD with CustomView: Why can't I animate my custom view?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cabasicanimation, mbprogresshud

This somehow doesn't work...why? How can I achieve a spinning custom propeller without making a gif out of the animation?

```
-(UIView *)propTest
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 37)];

    UIImageView *movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37 , 37)];

    movablePropeller.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MovablePropeller"];


    [view addSubview:movablePropeller];
    movablePropeller.center = view.center;

    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI)];
    rotation.cumulative = true;
    rotation.duration = 1.2f; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = INFINITY; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.

    [movablePropeller.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];

    return view;
}

-(void)presentMyHud
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:hud];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    hud.customView = [self propTest];
    hud.detailsLabelText = @"Getting data";
    [hud show:YES];
}
```

But my propeller stays static...

Answer (score 0):

If the propeller is not spinning, that can happen if you didn’t immediately add this `view` to the view hierarchy. Generally, it’s prudent to add the view to the view hierarchy *before* you `addAnimation`.

```
- (UIView *)addPropellerToView:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 37)];

    // make sure to add it to the view hierarchy

    [view addSubview:containerView];

    // if you want to center it, set its `center` to be in the middle of the `bounds` ... don't use `center`

    containerView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.origin.x + view.bounds.size.width / 2, view.bounds.origin.y + view.bounds.size.height / 2);

    // I'd just use the `bounds` of the container view; reducing the risk that we get its coordinates wrong

    UIImageView *movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];

    movablePropeller.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MovablePropeller"];
    movablePropeller.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    [containerView addSubview:movablePropeller];

    // never set the center of a view to the center of its super view ... those are two different coordinate systems.
    // in this case, this line isn't needed at all, so I'll remove it.
    //
    //     movablePropeller.center = containerView.center;

    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = @(0);
    rotation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
    rotation.cumulative = true;
    rotation.duration = 1.2f;
    rotation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

    [movablePropeller.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];

    return containerView;
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

---

Some unrelated observations:

- If you want to center view A in the middle of view B, set view A’s `center` to coordinates to the midpoint of B’s `bounds`, not to B’s `center`. E.g., you never want to do:

  ```
  A.center = B.center;
  ```

  What you want is:

  ```
  A.center = CGPointMake(B.bounds.origin.x + B.bounds.size.width / 2, B.bounds.origin.y + B.bounds.size.height / 2);
  ```

  I know it looks like it should be the same thing, but it’s not. A’s `center` is defined, like `frame`, in the coordinate system of B. But B’s `center` is defined in the coordinate system *of its superview,* which might be completely different. Sometimes you won’t notice the difference (specifically if B’s `origin` is `{0, 0}`), but it suggests a misunderstanding of the different coordinate systems, and if B isn’t at `{0, 0}`, then everything will be wrong.
- You can use `NSNumber` literals, replacing `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]` with `@(0)`.
- You really don’t need that container view, so you could simplify the routine, like below.

  ```
  - (UIView *)addPropellerTo:(UIView *)view {
      UIImageView *movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 37)];
      movablePropeller.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MovablePropeller"];
      movablePropeller.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
      [view addSubview:movablePropeller];
      movablePropeller.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.origin.x + view.bounds.size.width / 2, view.bounds.origin.y + view.bounds.size.height / 2);

      CABasicAnimation *rotation;
      rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
      rotation.fromValue = @(0);
      rotation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
      rotation.cumulative = true;
      rotation.duration = 1.2f;
      rotation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

      [movablePropeller.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];

      return movablePropeller;
  }
  ```